# How to pass keyboard navigation focus to generated xaml in WPF? And how to return it back?

Tags: wpf, xaml, keyboard

I have Content Control and here I am generating view, and now I want to pass here kayboard nagivation focus. And when I click "Back" I would like to back to previous keyboard navigation focus.

Answer (score 0):

You must first find the control that is now the focus with `FocusManager`, and then navigate with the `VisualTreeHelper` of all the children of the parent element, and when the current item tabindex decreases by one and the control tabindex equals the focus.

Note the following example to clarify the explanation.

```
private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Control focusedControl = (Control)FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);

   DependencyObject child;
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(focusedControl.Parent); i++)
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(focusedControl.Parent, i);
        if (child is Control)
        {
            if (((Control)child).TabIndex == focusedControl.TabIndex - 1)
               ((Control)child).Focus();
        }
    }
}
```